# How to upload a file to a webview via ACTION_SEND intent

Tags: android, android-intent, webview

I am trying to upload a file to a webview app via the ACTION_SEND intent. I already have it working if they choose to upload a file when inside the app, using the openFileChooser, but I need it to work when they click share from, say, the documents or gallery apps. So, I pretty much need to BYPASS openFileChooser, because a file as already been chosen and it's Uri is inside my Intent, I just need to actually upload it. I would like to piggy back off of the way openFileChooser does it, but am not sure how to do so.

I think my biggest hurdle is not knowing how to get/create/ignore ValueCallback uploadMsg, unless of course, there's a way to avoid that completely.

Here is my intent and openFileChooser, but I need to BYPASS that on receiving of the intent so I have

```
intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    if(intent != null){
        intentAction = intent.getAction();
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(intentAction)){
            if(intentAction.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_SEND)){
                if(intent.getExtras()!=null){
                   //get file from extra and piggyback off upload handler used in openFileChooser
                }
            }
        }
```

and my openFileChooser which works fine, with user input, but I need to be able to do it WITHOUT user input on receiving of the intent

```
WebChromeClient chromeClient = new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType,
                                    String capture) {
                mUploadHandler = new UploadHandler(WebFragment.this);
                mUploadHandler.openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType, capture);
        }
```

So I need to somehow get a valid ValueCallback Uri to set as the upload message for creating an openFileChooser so that when I do the mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result) (taken from google's webkit package) in here

```
void onResult(int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED && mCaughtActivityNotFoundException) {
        mCaughtActivityNotFoundException = false;
        return;
    }

    Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK ? null
            : intent.getData();
    if (result == null && intent == null && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        File cameraFile = new File(mCameraFilePath);
        if (cameraFile.exists()) {
            result = Uri.fromFile(cameraFile);
            mController.getActivity().sendBroadcast(
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, result));
        }
    }

    mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
    mHandled = true;
    mCaughtActivityNotFoundException = false;
}
```

So, long story short, I need a valid `ValueCallback<Uri>` in order to piggyback off of Android/webkit's onReceiveValue(result)/WebView's upload handler, and am not sure how to get it without user input to open the upload from device.

Comment: If you add some code to your question, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Okay, I edited the comment. Let me know if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

As the first comment on your question says, more code would help diagnose this but the generic way to receive an `ACTION_SEND` intent is as follows.

Configure `ACTION_SEND` as an [Intent Filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) in the Android Manifest for your Activity.

```
<application>
...
    <activity>
    ...
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />    
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />   
    </intent-filter>
```

You can optionally set a number of `<data android:mimeType=XXX>` elements if you only want to accept certain kinds of files.

Then in your Activity you can use the `getIntent()` and `Intent.getData()` methods to process the incoming send intent.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Uri sharedFile = intent.getData();
    // We can now use the URI of the file / item in
    // the WebView. Probably want to do this after onCreate
    // so that the WebView has fully initialised.
}
```